# Mentoría y equipos de aprendizaje grupal

Tags: discusión, enseñanza-aprendizaje

Tengo una propuesta para mejorar la comunidad de desarrolladores que andamos en Stack Overflow en español.

Así como recién han iniciado con los webcast, propongo que formemos grupos de aprendizaje colectivo donde haya al menos personas que con experiencia dispuestos a compartir su conocimiento con nuevos desarrolladores, entusiastas y todo aquel que desee entrar al equipo por el gusto de aprender y compartir.

**La idea es la siguiente:**

1. Un equipo de 2 personas como mínimo que tengan experiencia en XYZ
   tecnología que serán los líderes/mentores en dicha tecnología.
2. Bienvenidos todos los que desean aprender.
3. Un ciclo de 4 sesiones grabadas en un Hangout: puede ser una cada 15 días y se hace en 2 meses o una semanalmente y se hace en 1 mes,
   con respecto a horarios propongo que sean fines de semana.
4. Las preguntas que salgan en dichas sesiones deberán ser publicadas y respondidas en StackOverflow en español.

**Finalidades:**

1. Hacer comunidad, integrar a diversos desarrolladores de diversos países que andamos en Stack Overflow en español.
2. Motivar al aprendizaje colectivo.
3. Capacitarnos entre nosotros para tener mayores ideas que nos permitan responder a las preguntas formuladas en esta comunidad.

¿Qué opinan?

Comment: Me gusta mucho la propuesta.

Comment: @fredyfx me parece una gran idea - permíteme pensar en esto unos días y nos juntamos para platicar sobre los detalles. ¿Te parece? Tengo el webcast esta semana así que espérame para la semana que viene.

Comment: epa! espero, ideas que se comparten logran generar grandes cambios! Saludos.

Comment: A mí me agrada la idea. Creo que hay que tener cuidado de que no sea una de las ideas que ya existen en SE que son los equipos. Al parecer esta idea tiene un rumbo diferente. Más información sobre los equipos aquí (en inglés): [The Goal of Teams: Our Follow-Up to Your Questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308601/1065197), [The Power of Teams: A Proposed Expansion of Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307513/1065197)

Comment: Hay que hacer esto! Por la razones dadas y por muchas mas.. todas las que nos llevan a seguir creciendo.

Comment: Está buena la idea! Vamos!!!

Comment: No soy experto, pero quisiera unirme al grupo y ayudar con lo poco que sé. Hay que hacerlo, buena idea.

Comment: Parece una idea excelente. Quisiera aportar mi granito de arena con mis conocimientos de C++.

Comment: Que alegría ver que cada vez mas personas se van sumando! Sigamos compartiendo ideas, veamos que podemos crear entre todos :) @LuiggiMendoza esa idea que mencionas sobre los TEAMS de SO tiene algo de parecido, no sabia de su existencia y gracias por el dato! Siento que esta propuesta esta siendo construida con cada comentario. Sigamos adelante!

Comment: @fredyfx ¿Disponemos los voluntarios de un punto de encuentro para compartir nuestro currículo/conocimientos? Sería ideal para saber qué tenemos y qué podemos ofrecer como grupo de mentoría.

Comment: Me agrada la idea @PaperBirdMaster te parece si el punto de encuentro sea un Google Hangout (un sábado/domingo) donde compartamos los CVs y demás detalles de cada uno que se ofrezca como voluntario?

Comment: @fredyfx un Google Hangout me parece ideal, aunque si *requerimos* videoconferencia no dispongo de WebCam.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, lo fundamental aquí es expresar las ideas y por la webcam no hay problema. Seguimos adelante!

Comment: Estimados, la propuesta tiene 1 mes y medio aprox. quienes se animan a estar como mentores? Le voy a ASP.net MVC C# + JavaScript

Comment: Siempre es una excelente idea armar grupos de trabajo y apoyo, no todos conocemos todo y siempre hay temas nuevas que van saliendo con el paso el tiempo, nueva tecnología que merece la pena aprender para no caer en la obsolecencia, yo puedo colaborar en lo que buenamente sepa, que no es mucho, pero en algo ayudaré.

Comment: @JuanM, Podrías crear un formulario para todos aquellos interesados, de tal manera que se pueda hacer un mailing una vez que terminemos de completar la organizacion al interno?

Comment: No soy un experto pero siquiera pudiera ayudar en lo mas minimo y asi estar aprendiendo .
Buen Trabajo Sigan asi :)

Comment: sabes? Discord viene muy bien equipada para las sesiones online, con el plus de manejar bots. Me uno al team ASP.net MVC C# + JavaScript

Comment: ¿Y si le damos play a la idea? Ya pasaron 2 años :D

Comment: @fredyfx yo me uno!

Comment: Yo estaba buscando una plataforma de mentoría en español, similar a codementor. Dejo este comentario por si esto se reactiva. ¡ Gracias !

Answer (score 10):

Para comenzar con esta iniciativa, me gustaría invitar a cualquier persona interesada en compartir una **serie de publicaciones a nuestro blog** a mandarme un correo electrónico a jgarza @ stackoverflow.com.

Incluyan lo siguiente en su correo:

- nombre completo
- nombre de usuario
- temas para compartir
- ¿cuantas publicaciones piensas que necesitaras para tu serie?
- ¿has contribuido a algún blog antes o tienes tu propio blog? comparte el enlace a ellos

Quiero destacar a los interesados y darles la oportunidad de compartir con el mundo algo de sus experiencias. Los temas que propongan tendrán que ser evaluados para asegurar que sean temas que ayuden, motiven, enseñen, y entretengan a la comunidad.

Si te interesa esta oportunidad, ponte al contacto conmigo.

Comment: Vamos con todo el power 2.0!